# Can someone assist translating a handwritten note I found? Possible Devanagari script

Tags: written-language, devanagari

EDITED:

I found a handwritten note that was folded. I don't know where it came from. It was located in a trash can in my home.  I live in rural United States.  No one in my house claims to know where the note came from.

I wondered if anyone can either tell me what the language is and possibly translate it?

I originally though that it was written right to left and so thought it was likely from the Middle East. Because of comments made it looks like I may have been looking at the note upside down. These early commentators thought it to be Devanagari script.

I apologize for the sloppy work with the question as it was posted very late and I should have waited until I was better prepared to formulate a proper question.

I am reposting the image rotated.

Any assistance is appreciated.
[image]

UPDATE 2: I had a coworker look at it and he thought it was Hindi but was unable to read it.  I started to look at it more in depth and I was seeing patterns.  The handwriting doesn't match exactly to Hindi type faces (just like my handwriting doesn't look like Times New Roman) so I am not sure if I got this right but I see the same word 3 times and it looks similar to:

आरव (Aarav)

see below:
[image]

Comment: It seems plausible that the letter is upside-down and this is a variant of Devangari script, but it is not Hindi.  It think it is Bengali, but I do not speak it so I cannot be sure.

Comment: I agree, the red steak across the paper looks like an upside-down check mark. The script is obviously either Devanagari or a relative of it. That would mean its probably from south Asia, though a middle eastern origin is somewhat possible. Pakistan was once a part of India.

Comment: Try here: https://forum.wordreference.com/forums/indo-iranian-languages.99/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for a translation, you're probably better off going to a forum dedicated to the language. You can find sub-forums for dozens of languages on unilang and wordreference. Even if you don't know what language it is, I imagine someone who speaks Hindi would at least be more familiar with the Devanagari script and be more able to pinpoint exactly what language is it.